# Why does [:lower:] return differently in bash depending on the existence of files?

Tags: bash

This just happened to me in bash:

```
$ echo HELLO|tr [:upper:] [:lower:]
hello
$ touch w
$ echo HELLO|tr [:upper:] [:lower:]
wwwww
$ echo [:upper:]
[:upper:]
$ echo [:lower:]
w
```

The obvious fix for the original problem is to quote the values given to tr.  My question is more about what's happening when I don't!

I managed to reduce the problem a little:

```
$ rm w
$ echo [:w:]
[:w:]
$ touch w
$ echo [:w:]
w
```

Can someone explain what's going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An expression like `[:lower:]` is [a glob pattern](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_13_01) if you don't enclose it in quotes. Thus, it matches a filename that is exactly one* of the characters in the square braces. What you probably want is to simply quote it:

```
$ tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' <<< ABC
abc
```

As hobbs points out in his comment, I should explain the inconsistency of why the behavior changes depending on if the file is present or not. If no file matching the glob exists, the behavior of bash is determined by whether or not the `nullglob` extension is enabled. It's disabled by default.

> If no matching file names are found, and the shell option nullglob is not enabled, the word is left unchanged.

Thus, if no file with a name consisting entirely of one of ':', 'l', 'o', 'w', 'e', or 'r' exists, the glob `[:lower:]` will expand to the word `[:lower:]`.

*Updated. As Glenn Jackman points out in his comment, I had previously mistakenly confused `[:lower:]` for `[[:lower:]]`. It *is* confusing. In most places where you apply regular expressions in POSIX utilities and shell commands the character class itself has to be explicitly wrapped with square braces. So `[a-z]` is `[[:lower:]]` in the `C` locale, for example. But `tr` breaks the rules and *implies* the square braces, such that `tr -d '[:lower:]'` is equivalent to `tr -d 'a-z'` in the `C` locale. So my excuse is that when `tr` is involved I regularly forget how many braces are actually needed. :P

Comment: And the inconsistency comes in because a glob pattern that matches no files expands to the literal pattern, instead of a list of no files. Which is why `echo *.c` probably gives you a list of C source files in the current directory, but `echo *.zzzz` prints `"*.zzzz"`.

Comment: Thanks to the both of you!  Looks like the colons were also a red herring.

Comment: @user3381528 The colons are important when using a *standard* (as defined by re_format(7) BSD and regex(7) Linux) character class. The colon is just another character when using a custom character class.

Comment: @kojiro What I meant was that they're not important in terms of the bash globbing, not that it's valid tr syntax.

Comment: A correction: `[[:lower:]]` is a glob pattern matching a single lowercase letter; `[:lower:]` is a bracket expression that will match `:` or `l` or  `o` or  `w` or  `e` or  `r`. If the OP did `touch u`, then `echo [:lower:]` would not have matched.

Comment: @glennjackman sigh. Thanks, `tr` always throws me for a loop. I updated the answer.